# returning multiple stored procedure result sets from a cfc

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I am trying to convert some pages from my app to use cfc's, and one page uses a stored procedure to retrieve a couple sets of data.

Now when I access the results, they act just like a if I used a `<cfquery>` tag, and all of the functionality that gives.  So now I am trying to use this same stored procedure in a cfc that I am building, and I would like to be able access the results in the same manner, and there in lies my problem.  I'm not sure how to return multiple queries from the function, without creating an array, which I have started.  By the way, the function is incomplete.  I was just trying to get something to work.  In the below setup I get an array of query objects, but I feel there is a better way to do it.

Here is the `<cffuntion>`:

```
<cffunction name="getProfileData" 
            access="public" 
            output="false" 
            returntype="string">

    <cfargument name="cusip" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="report_date" type="date" required="true">
    <cfset var errorMessage = "everything is good">

    <cftry>
        <cfstoredproc datasource="#dsn#" procedure="prc_asset_profile_retrieve">
            <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#cusip#" dbvarname="@cusip">
            <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#report_date#" dbvarname="@reportDate">
            <cfprocresult name="profile_head" resultset="1">
            <cfprocresult name="attribution" resultset="2">
            <cfprocresult name="characteristics" resultset="3">
            <cfprocresult name="exposure" resultset="4">
            <cfprocresult name="weights" resultset="5">
            <cfprocresult name="holdings" resultset="6">
        </cfstoredproc>

        <cfset var profileArray = []>
        <cfset #ArrayAppend(profileArray,profile_head)#>

        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfset errorMessage = "something happened">
        </cfcatch>          
    </cftry>

    <cfreturn profileArray>
</cffunction>
```

When I output some test data, it matches up

```
<cfset count = fund_profile.getProfileData("#cusip#","#report_date#")> 
<cfdump var="#count[1]#">
<cfoutput>
    From cfc (##count[1].recordCount##): #count[1].recordCount#<br>
    From stored proc (##profile_head.recordCount##): #profile_head.recordCount#
</cfoutput>
```

I get:

**From cfc (#count[1].recordCount#): 1

From stored proc (#profile_head.recordCount#): 1**

But the second way looks so much cleaner.

```
   -----------------------------WORKING SOLUTION------------------------------
```

So after working with the answer from @leigh, I came up with this.

Here is the full cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Fund Profile" hint="This is the cfc that will do the processing of all fund profile information" output="false">
     <cfproperty name = "result1"> <!--- PROFILE HEAD --->
     <cfproperty name = "result2"> <!--- ATTRIBUTION --->
     <cfproperty name = "result3"> <!--- CHARACTERISTICS --->
     <cfproperty name = "result4"> <!--- EXPOSURE --->
     <cfproperty name = "result5"> <!--- WEIGHTS --->
     <cfproperty name = "result6"> <!--- HOLDINGS --->

     <cffunction name="init" 
            displayname="init" 
            hint="This will initialize the object" 
            access="public" 
            output="false" 
            returnType="Any">

        <cfargument name="dsn"  type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="cusip" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="report_date" type="date" required="true" />

        <cfset variables.dsn = #arguments.dsn#>
        <cfset variables.cusip = #arguments.cusip#>
        <cfset variables.report_date = #arguments.report_date#>

        <cfscript>
            getProfiledata(cusip,report_date);
        </cfscript>     

        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="getProfileData" 
            access="private" 
            output="false" 
            returntype="void">

        <cfargument name="cusip" type="string" required="true">
        <cfargument name="report_date" type="date" required="true">

        <cfstoredproc datasource="#dsn#" procedure="prc_asset_profile_retrieve">
             <!--- STORED PROCEDURE HASN'T CHANGED.  SEE ABOVE FOR CODE --->
        </cfstoredproc>

        <cfscript>
            setProfilehead(profile_head);
            setAttribution(attribution);
            setCharacteristics(characteristics);
            setExposure(exposure);
            setWeights(weights);
            setHoldings(holdings);
        </cfscript>

        <cfreturn>
    </cffunction>

    <!--- NOT GOING TO INCLUDE ALL SETTERS AND GETTERS, --->
    <!--- BECAUSE THEY ARE ALL THE SAME OTHER THAN THE NAMES --->

    <cffunction name="setProfileHead" access="private">
        <cfargument name="ProfileHead">
        <cfset variables.result1 = arguments.ProfileHead>       
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="getProfileHead" access="public" returntype="query">
        <cfreturn variables.result1>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Here is the code from the calling page:

```
<cfset fund_profile = CreateObject("component", "CFCs.fund_profile").init("#dsn#","#cusip#","#report_date#")>
<cfset profile_head = fund_profile.getProfileHead()>
```

Sorry for all the code, but I wanted to make the code available.  So does anyone see any problems with what I came up with?

Comment: This doesn't seem that good. Everytime you want data, you have to run `getProfileData` to execute the Stored Procedure, and then run another `get` method to get the updated information. Is this efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create other methods in the CFC that would each be responsible for returning a result from the stored proc. In the main method , call setters 
setProfileHead(profilehead:profileHead)

```
<cffunction name=ProfileHead>
    <cfarguments name=ProfileHead />
    <cfset variables.profilehead = arguments.profilehead>
 </cffunction>
```

Then...

```
<cffunction name=GetProfileHead>
    <cfreturn variables.profileHead />
</cffuction>
```

Comment: So, I'm a bit confused.   When you say "main method", you mean the one from my original post, that contains the actual stored proc?  Or do you mean the cfm page that is calling the cfc?

Comment: I posted that yesterday.  If you look at the original post that I edited today, you'll see what I did.

Comment: How is this going to work when the `variables` scope is private to the CFC, so the invoking page won't see it at all

Comment: The invoking page will see it if it calls getProfileHead because thats what it returns.

Answer (score 8):

A function can only return a single value. If you wish to return multiple values, you will need to use some type of complex object (an array, structure, ...) If arrays are not intuitive enough, you could place the queries in a structure and return that instead. Then the calling page could access the queries by name, rather than index.

(Side note, be sure to properly var scope/localize all function variables.)

```
 <cfset var data = {}>
 ...
 <!--- store query results in structure --->
 <cfset data.profile_head = profile_head>
 <cfset data.attribution = attribution>
 ... 
 <cfset data.holdings = holdings>
 <!--- return structure --->
 <cfreturn data>
```

Comment: you could use a bean approach and have a "get" for each of the result set (where each result would be a "property" of the component).. then you would have #objProfile.getprofileHead()# which would return the result set just as if it were the "name" of the proc result set. That's what Jim's suggesting. However, for ease of transition from what you are use to, I suspect Leigh's approach is a better fit for you.

Comment: Yep, I was not sure about his setup, so I took the generic approach. But beans would be a good way to approach it too. (Edit: I see I misread Jim's suggestion. Sorry, @Jim. +1  :)

Comment: I think I'm going to give both methods a shot.  I have used the setter/getter type structure before, so I am familiar with the concept.  I'll give both a try and see which one I like better.