# How to return multiple results from a stored procedure in a CFC?

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I've seen an identical question here [returning multiple stored procedure result sets from a cfc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982918/returning-multiple-stored-procedure-result-sets-from-a-cfc) but I'm not able find a good solution.

I have an SP which returns about 8 results/queries. I want to output the queries into variables that can be returned by other functions. This is what I mean:

```
<cffunction name="AllOrders" returntype="query">
  <cfstoredproc procedure="SELAllOrders" datasource="mydb">
   <cfprocresult name="rsClosedOrders" resultset="1">
   <cfprocresult name="rsOpenOrders" resultset="2">
   <cfprocresult name="rsPendingOrders" resultset="3">
   <cfprocresult name="rsPaidOrders" resultset="4">
  </cfstoredproc>
</cffunction>
<!--- GET A RESULT TO RETURN TO CALLING PAGE --->
<cffunction name="GetClosedOrders" returntype="query">
   <!--- How do I return the result/query from the above CFC named rsClosedOrders from here? ---!>
<cfreturn rsClosedOrders/>
</cfunction>
```

How could I get the `rsClosedOrders` result out of the `AllOrders()` function and made available to another method, in this case `GetClosedOrders()`?

Comment: The answer is the same as on the other thread. Within AllOrders, run the proc.  Put all of the resultsets into a structure. Have the function return that structure. Call AllOrders from your other function and extract the key containing the resultset you need. Obviously that is a bit wasteful as it retrieves all eight resultsets from the db every time, whether they are used or not.  However, there is not much you can do about it unless you redesign the stored procedure.

Comment: Side note, in case the above is not psuedo code, be sure to `var/local` scope ALL of the function local variables (including the results) to avoid potential threading issues.

Comment: @Leigh The reason it returns many result sets is because the calling page requires all that data at once to show counts of Orders (similar to how Outlook shows how many emails you have e.g. `Inbox(45)`). This is also just one of MANY SPs that return multiple results. Another example is the main `Product` page that returns basic info, technical sheets, notes, and history queries. It makes sense to have it all in one SP because its all to do with the `Product` page.

Comment: It all depends.  Just because the data is related does not mean it should always be grouped and returned together.   For example if you had multiple components accessing different pieces of Product information, it makes more sense to return only what is needed, rather than returning everything, every time.  That said, it makes sense to return a bunch of "counts" ie Inbox(45),Sent(55),etcetera...  as a group.  However, typically you would return the counts as separate columns in a single resultset - not one resultset per count. But again, it all depends...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially what Leigh was describing above and with proper var scoping applied.  Note, this is what you're asking for, but it's not a very efficient method.  I would break the stored proc into separate procs, or just eliminate it and put the queries directly in your code.

```
<cffunction name="AllOrders" returntype="struct">
  <cfset local.resultSets = {}>
  <cfstoredproc procedure="SELAllOrders" datasource="mydb">
   <cfprocresult name="local.resultSets.rsClosedOrders" resultset="1">
   <cfprocresult name="local.resultSets.rsOpenOrders" resultset="2">
   <cfprocresult name="local.resultSets.rsPendingOrders" resultset="3">
   <cfprocresult name="local.resultSets.rsPaidOrders" resultset="4">
  </cfstoredproc>
  <cfreturn local.resultSets>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="GetClosedOrders" returntype="query">
  <cfset local.resultSets = AllOrders()>
  <cfreturn local.resultSets.rsClosedOrders/>
</cfunction>

<cffunction name="GetOpenOrders" returntype="query">
  <cfset local.resultSets = AllOrders()>
  <cfreturn local.resultSets.rsOpenOrders/>
</cfunction>

<cffunction name="GetPendingOrders" returntype="query">
  <cfset local.resultSets = AllOrders()>
  <cfreturn local.resultSets.rsPendingOrders/>
</cfunction>

<cffunction name="GetPaidOrders" returntype="query">
  <cfset local.resultSets = AllOrders()>
  <cfreturn local.resultSets.rsPaidOrders/>
</cfunction>
```

Comment: It is currently in my code, but I'm having problems adding more 'things' to may application that need to use the same procedures. I end up executing the same SP on multiple pages, thereby repeating my code.

Comment: That means you need to abstract that code into a service layer where it will be reusable.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do with this CFC right? Keep it all in a CFC that can return data depending on what requests it. Or have I got it wrong?

Comment: Assuming the SP could not be changed, I would run it in the variables scope of the cfc as opposed to inside a function.  That way you only have to run it once and can return any number of results sets.  The way you have it, you have to run the proc twice if you want two of the 8 results sets.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you can handle this.

1. You could refactor the stored procedure so that it's not returning 8 different result sets then just call the stored procedure you needed.
2. You could call the SP that returns all the 8 sets and just use the one you need, like so:

   ```
   <cffunction name="getClosedOrders" returntype="query">
       <cfstoredproc procedure="SELAllOrders" datasource="mydb">
           <cfprocresult name="rsClosedOrders" resultset="1">
       </cfstoredproc>

       <cfreturn rsClosedOrders>
   </cffunction>
   ```

Basically creating a function that only returns one result set out of the eight.  This is horribly inefficient though.

Comment: Your first suggestion may be good or bad advice depending on what the SP does and why it returns more than one result set.

Comment: Valid point, and one of the reasons I gave a couple of options... I didn't want to assume anything.  But you're 100% correct there.

Comment: @DanBracuk The SP is returning counts of orders to show in a div - quite similar to how Outlook shows how many emails you have in your inbox.

Comment: @volumeone - Is there a specific reason you must return each count as a *separate* resultset? Typically, I would return related counts as either a single resultset with multiple columns, ie CountA, CountB, ... CountX OR as a single resultset with multiple rows.

Comment: @Leigh The reason is that one of the resultsets returns more than just a count - it also returns count by status. So `rsPendingOrders` will return something like `Pending(50) > Unpaid (10) > NoStock(30) > Unreleased(10)`. Its exactly like how sub-folders work in Outlook where the each sub-total aggregates up to the total to show your inbox total. I agree it probably could be better done, but at the time it seemed a decent way to grab everything at once and show sub-levels for `PendingOrders` only.

Comment: @volumeone - Well, that sounds more like a case for a single resultset overall, like how you might retrieve any tree or structure with multiple levels.

Comment: @Leigh I'll have to look into it. At the time I couldn't have multiple counts that are dependent on multiple where statements in a single result set. For example `SELECT Count(OrderID) FROM dbo.Order WHERE Status = 1` would return just OpenOrders. Then I need to return a count of ClosedOrders using `WHERE Status = 2` and so on. But with sub-levels included _only_ on PendingOrders, I can't use a `Union` either

Comment: @volumeone - *Re: I can't use a Union either* Sure are a lot of restrictions  ;-)  Next it will be no derived tables, temp tables or table variables either! Seriously though, does "can't use a union" mean you were unable to figure out how to work it into the existing SQL or something else? Obviously there are a few different ways you could slice it, but a lot depends on which options are available to you.

Comment: @Leigh I was unable to figure it out. I should look into it again and try to get into it one resultset that's quick because it has to run constantly whenever the page is refreshed for hundreds of users.

Comment: @volumeone - Yes, stored procedures offer a lot of control and opportunity for optimization. Even if it requires returning two resultsets, that is a lot better than eight.